# Look at data between the ranges of. (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel

My aim is to add up the amount of data in cells between a certain date range. I have 2 columns which are dates and ajacent to those are amounts of beans I have in the bean bank. I entered this formula, =SUMIF(P34:P44,">=22/01/18",Q34:Q44) and it gives me my result! but i want the result between a range so if i ever want to see the bean between the jan 28th and the Feb 5th i can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee's answer works perfectly well, but you could also consider using [SUMIFS()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumifs-function).
It can include multiple criteria to specify which values to sum:

`SUMIFS(sum_range, range1,criteria1, [range2],[criteria2],...)`

For your example, the formula would be:

`=SUMIFS(Q34:Q44,P34:P44,">=28/01/2018",P34:P44,"<=05/02/2018")`

Comment: My solution is rather a kludge compared with your suggestion - `SUMIFS` is ideal for this scenario, thanks.

Comment: Hey, I'm going to throw a point your way for a great effort. This is a wonderful place to learn a lot of things about Excel that you didn't know before. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
=SUMIF(P34:P44,">=28/01/2018",Q34:Q44)-SUMIF(P34:P44,">05/02/2018",Q34:Q44)
```